# Background Color Change onload JavaScript+Html

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to write my own website, however I had an idea to have an Array of background colors that the site would change to at random (but not repeating the same color back to back) every time the page is loaded / refreshed. I remember doing something very similar to this when I was in school but I just can't quite remember how it was done.

This is what I have so far, I have been fiddling with this for about a day and just can't quite figure out what I am missing.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var color = new Array();
color[0] = "#CC99FF";
color[1] = "#FF99CC";
color[2] = "#FF9999";
color[3] = "#FFCC99";
color[4] = "#FFFF99";
color[5] = "#CCFF99";
color[6] = "#99FF99";
color[7] = "#99FFCC";
color[8] = "#66FFFF";
color[9] = "#66CCFF";

function changeColor()
{
  var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color[randomColor];

}
--!>
</script>
</head>
<body onload="changeColor()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that your question had a second part, which is to not repeat the same color twice.  Since you are doing this on a reload, it becomes a little trickier since you cannot just store the last color in a simple variable.

For this, I decided to utilized [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).  I leveraged some of the other answers as well that mentioned you need to use the style property on the body element.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/t8kw2z6w/7/) of the solution and the code is below:

As mentioned, you need to use the style property to set the background color:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor=color[randomColor];
```

Then, you need to keep looking for an index that wasn't used in the last run:

First, I grab the currently stored index, or -1 if it doesn't exist.

```
var lastColorIndex = localStorage.getItem('lastColorIndex') || -1;
```

Then set do the loop while the two indices aren't equal or if random color is -1 (this is for on the initial page load). Note that we are using `==` for a 'truthy' check since `localStorage` will return a string and `Math.random()` returns a number;

```
while(lastColorIndex == randomColor || randomColor === -1)
```

Finally, set the randomColor value into local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem('lastColorIndex',randomColor);
```

All together now:

```
function changeColor()
{
    var lastColorIndex = localStorage.getItem('lastColorIndex') || -1;
  var randomColor = -1;
    while(lastColorIndex == randomColor || randomColor === -1) {        
  randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
        console.log('LastIndex: ' + lastColorIndex + ',RandomColor: ' + randomColor);
    };
    localStorage.setItem('lastColorIndex',randomColor);
    //console.log(randomColor);
  console.log(color[randomColor]);
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor=color[randomColor];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you must access to you body style :

```
function changeColor() {
  var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color[randomColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the background color like that

```
function changeColor()
{
  var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
  document.body.style.background = color[randomColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the background color property correctly.Use it this way.

```
function changeColor()
{
  var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color[randomColor]; //THIS IS IMP

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I still am unable to get this to work though, any other ideas for me?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this fiddle (click 'run' several times to simulate reload) :

http://jsfiddle.net/4j61r6go/

```
function changeColor()
{
  var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
  console.log(color[randomColor]);
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor=color[randomColor];
};
```

you should call 'changeColor' in windowor document 'onload'.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a code in a theme hope this will help you

```
        $('.animated-bg').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            colors = ['#ec008c', '#00bcc3', '#5fb26a', '#fc7331'];

        setInterval(function(){
            var color = colors.shift();
            colors.push(color);
            $this.animate({backgroundColor: color}, 2000);
        },4000);
    });
```